# AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, xlwings

```
def Cleanse(infile):
    import xlwings as xw
    dataset= xw.Book(infile)
    xw.save()
```

Hi, I'm using the above code. It runs the first 2 lines (plus the function header) fine, but fine it says save does not exist. I have checked my version, it is 0.10.4, the latest version. I get the same problem with ".close".

Comment: You need to call `save()` on the book object, not on the module. `dataset.save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line, you have to call save() on the dataset not xw:

```
def Cleanse(infile):
    import xlwings as xw
    dataset= xw.Book(infile)
    dataset.save()
```